# React rerenders after each state change, how to design the component structure?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component `OrdersMap` showing a map on which I have markers. I would like to be able to click on the markers and see some details using `OrderDetails` component related to the marker. I created a state variable `selectedOrder`, which stores the data to show in `OrderDetails`. The issue is that each time I click the marker, the whole component rerenders, which I do not want, because the map is pretty heavy. Could someone suggest how to achieve this?

Here is the simplified version of the code:

```
export default function OrdersMap({ orders }) {
  const [selectedOrder, setSelectedOrder] = React.useState(null)

  return (
    <>
      <MyMap>
        {orders.map((order) => (
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedOrder(order)}>{order.id}</button>
        ))}
      </MyMap>

      {selectedOrder && <OrderDetails order={selectedOrder} />}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: u can memoize the orders map component(u need to extract it to a separate component first and then memoize it)? u can read through this as well for a better understanding on how react updates the dom

Answer (score 0):

So, extracting the component with `React.memo` did the job. The same props do not trigger updating the map, if you use it.

```
export default function OrdersMap({ orders }) {
  const [selectedOrder, setSelectedOrder] = React.useState(null)

  return (
    <>
      <MemoizedMyMap orders={orders} setSelectedOrder={setSelectedOrder()} />

      {selectedOrder && <OrderDetails order={selectedOrder} />}
    </>
  )
}

const MemoizedMyMap = React.memo(({ orders, setSelectedOrder }) => (
  <MyMap>
    {orders.map((order) => (
      <button onClick={() => setSelectedOrder(order)}>{order.id}</button>
    ))}
  </MyMap>
))
```